# Receiving android emulator crash in firebase with production application

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Some context:
I have an android application in production and in the past weeks i'm seeing an increase of reports in firebase crashlytics from android emulators calling activities outside normal flows ( for example in a chat application, starting the profile of a contact without going first to the contact chat. )

The app crashes because is expecting some data that is not currently available, but my question is:
Can google play scanner to check for virus in apks be the reason behind this runs in emulators ? Is someone having this kind of crashes too? Or i have one user testing my apk with an emulator ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provider more information on the crash that you're seeing, and the code that produces it. Without that, it will be impossible for anyone to provide a meaningful answer. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your response maybe i didn't explain it correctly.
The crash is not the issue, is more of a question about if someone is having this kind of reports ( emulators starting random activities and crashing the app for whatever reason ) and if you know if the responsable of this executions can be google play scans for virus or is an user trying to do something with the apk.

Comment: If you want a conversation with others about some problem, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask. Try a discussion forum instead, such as Reddit.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.